Using the same page template for all my pages in Wordpress
I have some pages in Wordpress and I want all of them to have the same basic structure like this:
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main>    
    <div class="page-wrapper">        
        <!-- Different page content here -->
    </div>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

I tried to do this on a page template:
<?php /* Template Name: Test page template */
get_template_part('templates/page');
?>
Test
</div>

And this on my page template page.php:
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main class="page-wrapper">
    <?php 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        the_content();
    endwhile; 
    ?>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

But it just injects the page.php and then puts my "Test" string after the footer. I need the test string to go inside the page-wrapper. How can I have a basic template like this for all my page templates?

Well move the "Test" string into the "page.php" file, before the call to get_footer()? I am not sure what the problem is here?

@Cyclonecode Well that is just ONE of my pages, I have like 20 pages (about, contact etc) and I want all to have a call to the header, the main content, the page wrapper, the actualy page content defined in each page tmeplate, and then the footer at the end. I want to not have to put all stuff around page-wrapper into each page template, if possible

This question, as written, doesn't make much sense. WP by default has a page.php template, and any content added on any page, unless a page specific template is chosen on a specific page, will output as you want. You don't need to use a get_template_part() - if you want a different template for specific pages, then you need to create something like page-custom.php and then select that template in your page attributes section when you're editing your page.
